# Python: Preventing a dict's key from being overwritten

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to convert an xml document to Python data structures.

A sample of the xml:

```
    <SOFTWARES>
        <PUBLISHER>Microsoft Corporation</PUBLISHER>
        <NAME>Microsoft Office Visio 2010</NAME>
        <VERSION>14.0.6029.1000</VERSION>
        <FOLDER>C:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/</FOLDER>
        <LANGUAGE>Language Neutral</LANGUAGE>
        <INSTALLDATE>2012/03/29</INSTALLDATE>
    </SOFTWARES>
    <SOFTWARES>
        <PUBLISHER>Microsoft</PUBLISHER>
        <NAME>Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553310) 64-Bit Edition</NAME>
        <INSTALLDATE>0000//0/0/00</INSTALLDATE>
    </SOFTWARES>
```

lxml.de has an excellent example of this: http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts

```
def xml_to_dict(element):
    return element.tag, dict(map(xml_to_dict, element)) or element.text
```

This produces a great dict of dicts which has but one flaw.  It will override existing keys.  So when the the process is complete I get:

```
'SOFTWARES': {
    'PUBLISHER': 'Microsoft',
    'NAME': 'Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553310) 64-Bit Edition',
    'INSTALLDATE': '0000//0/0/00',
},
```

Which is the last SOFTWARES block, regardless of how many were before it.  lxml's function works well because it's recursive but I want to write something that can handle duplicate keys.  Preferably by just tossing the SOFTWARES dicts in a list and I can just iterate through the list when the time comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution for this specific case:

```
map(xml_to_dict, xml_document)
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I'd like to keep the dicts if possible.  Just add dicts with duplicate keys to a list.

Comment: @PhilipCammarata: This will give you a very strange format.  You will never know if a value is a list or not, so all of your code will need special cases.  Either always use a list, or never.

Comment: The sample input looks like a list of SOFTWARES blocks, each of which contains no repeated keys. The natural data model for this is a list of dicts (one dict per SOFTWARE block). This is exactly what @Sven's code does.

Comment: If you're more generally worried about handling values for repeated keys, you can arrange for *every* value of a dict to be a list. In your case you'll end up with a dict containing just one key, 'SOFTWARES', whose value is a list... exactly the list generated by @Sven's answer.